# is the /data/local/tmp folder exposed for all non rooted android devices?

Tags: android, adb

I was able to run busybox binary on multiple non rooted android devices by copying the binary to /data/local/tmp folder using adb, although a few of the binaries did not work due to permission issues (due to SELinux). I do not have write permissions to any other folders in the device, but i was able to write to, and change permissions of busybox using chmod on the /data/local/tmp/ folder!

What is the special about the /data/local/tmp/ folder on non rooted devices?
why is it exposed in the non rooted devices ? is there a specific purpose ?

NOTE: the non rooted devices where running android 4.3, 4.4 and also 5 (lollipop)

Answer (score 2):

This temporary folder is used to store `.apk` files during `adb install`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it then makes sense as to why I was able to access this across non rooted devices. Is there any official documentation from google detailing how this folder is used ?, asking because the way it exists works for me fine, but what about future versions of Android, might this folder be deprecated (write and execute permissions) ?